# Searching data from array in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this code, which creates a `textfield` and a `button` to let the user search for data in an array:

```
//Creates a form to search data, list for it and buttons to sort the list.
            rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
            final TextField searchTextField;
            searchTextField = new TextField ();
            rightPanel.add(searchTextField);
            rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
            JButton searchConfirmButton = new JButton("Search");
            rightPanel.add(searchConfirmButton);
            searchConfirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    try {
                        search = searchTextField.getText();
                        int index = Arrays.asList(data).indexOf(search);
                        for (String result : data) {
                            if (result.contains(search)) {
                                System.out.println(result);
                                System.out.println(index);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {

                    }
                }
            });
```

But whenever I search for the data, whether it exists or not, the program returns me an `nullpointerexception` with the following content:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at program.Program$4$1.actionPerformed(Program.java:233)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In this case, row 233 contains this line `if (result.contains(search)) {`

Comment: exception where? stacktrace please

Comment: By catching the NullPointerException, you're hiding all the information that Java prints to help you find where the exception comes from. You're thus hiding the bug and its cause rather than examining the cause of the bug and fixing it. Remove the try/catch, and post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I edited the post and added the contents of the exception.

Comment: there seems to be a null-value in your `data`

Comment: @danrodi, still doesn't help. We don't know what line 233 is. It is up to you to look at the variable used on the line and determine which one is null and then solve the problem. This is basic debugging.

Comment: @camickr I mentioned it in the post above, line 233 is `if (result.contains(search)) {`

Comment: Well, it still doesn't change my answer, one of the variable is null. Add some System.out.println(...) statements to you code to see which variable is null and then fix the problem. We don't have access to you code so I'm not sure how you expect us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data looks like an array type that can hold data values or null pointers.  You should try:

```
System.out.println("Found index: " + index);
for (String result : data) {
    if (result != null && result.contains(search)) {
        System.out.println("Found result: " + result);
    }
    //If you are still confused than the right else here will help.
}
```

If, for example, you split a string with two spaces in a row by space, then depending on your function parameters to split(), you can end up with an empty string in that location and you need to skip it effectively.